# Pivot columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have 3 columns in SQL - Name, ID and Period:

```
Name    CarID    Period
--------------------- 
Bob     121      Jan 08 
Bob     123      Jan 08 
Bob     121      Feb 08 
Steve   121      Jan 08
Ruth    139      Feb 08
```

I need to pivot the CarID alongside unique Name and Period, i.e.:

```
Name    Period   Col1    Col2   Col3
-------------------------------------
Bob     Jan 08   121     123    NULL
Bob     Feb 08   121     NULL   NULL
Steve   Jan 08   121     NULL   NULL
Ruth    Feb 08   139     NULL   NULL
```

My problem is, a named user could have 1 or x number of CarID's against their name. I've tried a few dynamic pivot queries out but they have all had to set the column header names.

Comment: You're looking for a "crosstab." See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: Looking at that, it seems you need to know how many columns you would need?

Comment: @bluefeet Brain malfunction on my part - I saw a Postgresql tag that wasn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that you can get the result that you want, but in order to successfully return multiple `carid` values for each `name` and `period`, I would use a windowing function like `row_number()` to generate a unique sequence for each partition of `name`/`period`.

Your query will start with using something like:

```
select name, carid, period,
  'col'+
    cast(row_number() over(partition by name, period
                            order by carid) as varchar(10)) seq
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e468d/4). This is going to give you the following data that you can then PIVOT into columns.

```
|  NAME | CARID | PERIOD |  SEQ |
|-------|-------|--------|------|
|   Bob |   121 | Feb 08 | col1 |
|   Bob |   121 | Jan 08 | col1 |
|   Bob |   123 | Jan 08 | col2 |
|  Ruth |   139 | Feb 08 | col1 |
| Steve |   121 | Jan 08 | col1 |
```

You can then convert this data into columns, using an aggregate function and a CASE expression similar to:

```
select 
  name, 
  period,
  max(case when seq = 'col1' then carid end) col1,
  max(case when seq = 'col2' then carid end) col2,
  max(case when seq = 'col3' then carid end) col3
from
(
  select name, carid, period,
    'col'+
      cast(row_number() over(partition by name, period
                              order by carid) as varchar(10)) seq
  from yourtable
) d
group by name, period;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e468d/5).  This can also be converted into columns using the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
select name, period, col1, col2, col3
from
(
  select name, carid, period,
    'col'+
      cast(row_number() over(partition by name, period
                              order by carid) as varchar(10)) seq
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(carid)
  for seq in (col1, col2, col3)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e468d/6).  The above two queries will work great if you have a limited number of values, but if you have unknown values, then you will have to use dynamic SQL to generate the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(seq) 
                    from
                    (
                      select 'col'+
                          cast(row_number() over(partition by name, period
                                                  order by carid) as varchar(10)) seq
                      from yourtable
                    ) d
                    group by seq
                    order by seq
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name, period,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select name, carid, period,
                ''col''+
                  cast(row_number() over(partition by name, period
                                          order by carid) as varchar(10)) seq
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(carid)
                for seq in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e468d/7). All versions will give you a result similar to:

```
|  NAME | PERIOD | COL1 |   COL2 |
|-------|--------|------|--------|
|   Bob | Feb 08 |  121 | (null) |
|  Ruth | Feb 08 |  139 | (null) |
|   Bob | Jan 08 |  121 |    123 |
| Steve | Jan 08 |  121 | (null) |
```